# Angular 8 Lazy Loading Syntax Not Working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement Lazy loading into my Angular 8 application but when I use the syntax provided in the official doc, my module gets loaded eagerly.

When I use the syntax that comes with angular 8:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'lazy',
  // The new import() syntax
  loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)
}];
```

I get no error but I don't get a new chunk when I build the app, and when navigationg to the module route, nothing appears in the Network tab of chrome. (Although I can navigate to the module just fine)

But if I rewrite it to:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'lazy',
  // The following string syntax for loadChildren is deprecated
  loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
}];
```

(which is the old syntax)
it works fine.

The module in question is definitely not imported anywhere else, the difference in result comes only from changing the syntax.

I'd like to know if there is something I'm missing there. I'm thinking maybe it's my Angular that isn't correctly set up to version 8 (or some other package)
So here's what I have with a `ng version`:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.4
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.4
@angular/cdk                      8.0.0
@angular/cli                      8.0.4
@angular/material                 8.0.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.4
@schematics/angular               8.0.4
@schematics/update                0.800.4
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

I did try to create a new sample project and managed to get it to work there, but from what I can see, both projects have the same version of everything.

Any idea what could cause the new syntax not to work?

Comment: Culd you try a new project on your own computer and see if the errors persists ? (if you did it already, then try on stackblitz instead and provide us with the link in case it does not work). Have you tried stopping and running your serve command again ?

Comment: I did manage to get it to work with a new project, and I don't know what difference there is between the packages of my actual project and the new sample project. I did try to re-run the serve command or even rebuilding but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Maybe you got `import` statement somewhere. Which causing loading.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's honestly hard to help you ...

Comment: What does your routing module look like? Check your imports/exports.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a lot of digging between trying to provide a minimal reproducible example, trying to update all my packages or reinstalling them, and simply digging through all my files and try to find what was wrong, I managed to fix the issue.

I essentially re-upgraded my app to angular 8 as if I was using angular 7 (even tho I was supposedly already using angular 8) using the commands `ng update @angular/cli --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only
ng update @angular/core --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only` as mentionned in [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14589#issuecomment-499982919)

This updated all the old syntax of lazy loading to the new one automatically and on building/serving I could finally see all the chunks for each module

Given that it was fixed with these commands, I believe the issue was with packages/dependencies somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much you just saved my own issue with ionic 4 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830851/webpack-chunks-are-unable-to-load-on-android-web-and-ios-are-fine-chunkloader you made my day

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question when i was having similar issues like

`module.ts is missing from the typescript compilation. please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property`

and

`error ts1323: dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is 'commonjs' or 'esnext`

I got the first error when i tried using static lazy loading import

`loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule`

i decided to use dynamic import

`loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)`

This threw the second error.

I then fixed it by simply adding `"module": "esNext"` to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` file and updated `"module": "es2015"` to `"module": "esNext"` in both `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.tns.json` files.

That solves the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for nrwl 8 in monorepo and Angular 8. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, dynamic mudole lazy loading works for me in angular 8

Answer (score 3):

Though the answer has been accepted, I even faced a similar issue and it was due to not adding a routing module to the lazyloaded module. Any module that is being loaded lazily must have their own routing module otherwise the app redirects to the default route. I know this is pretty basic but sometimes we tend to ignore this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Issue for me was in the `tsconfig.json`. Once I updated the property `"module"` to `"esnext"`, it worked fine.