# Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk ... " only with firefox (Angular 9.1.2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firefox

I don't understand why app my don't work on Firefox but works on Chrome.

[image: error in firefox]

Remove `loadChildren` with `import()` works...

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {LayoutComponent} from './layout/layout.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'components', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'components',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/component-creator/component-creator.module').then(m => m.ComponentCreatorModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'templates',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/template-creator/template-creator.module').then(m => m.TemplateCreatorModule)
      },
    ]
  },

  // Not found
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'components'},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    enableTracing: false, // tracing for debug
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Note: `<base href="/">`

Any ideas ?

Thank you  !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 8 Lazy Loading Syntax Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748335/angular-8-lazy-loading-syntax-not-working)

Comment: I try to do some changes in tsconfig but nothing changes. Thank you so @AlexandraPetrova